# I'm having dificulties with output problems in my Go code

Tags: go, logic

I'm new here and to programming. I am trying to improve my programming logic by doing some exercises in my preferred languages such as Python and Go.

In this particular case, my issue is with Go.

The code basically should print the following:

```
Example

First person info:
Name: Mary
Age: 19
Second person info:
Name: John
Age: 20
```

```
The average age of Mary and John is 19.5 years
```

To solve this exercise, I tried the following code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var name1 int
    var name2 int
    var age1, age2 int
    var average float32
    fmt.Println("First person info:")
    fmt.Print("Name: ")
    fmt.Scan(&name1)
    fmt.Print("Age: ")
    fmt.Scan(&age1)
    fmt.Println("Second person info:")
    fmt.Print("Name: ")
    fmt.Scan(&name2)
    fmt.Print("Age: ")
    fmt.Scan(&age2)

    average = float32((age1 + age2) / 2)
    fmt.Printf("\nThe average age of %d and %d is %f years", &name1, &name2, &average)

}
```

I've tried some variations, trying to convert some variables, but the thing is that the output is like below:

```
First person info:
```

```
Name: Mary
```

```
Age: Second person info:
```

```
Name: Age:
```

```
The average age of %s and %s is %.2f years 0xc000018088 0xc0000180a0 0xc0000180b8
```

```
PS C:\Users\alexi\Meu Drive\Programação\golang>
```

So, the code don't show the `print` function one by one. I answer the first name (`name1`) and soon I answer it, the output brings all others, all together (age, second person info etc.)   I tried everything and can't understand what possibly went wrong...

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

1. The `fmt.Print` function does not add a newline character to the string you're printing. So you probably want to change lines like `fmt.Print("Name: ")` to `fmt.Println("Name:")` or `fmt.Print("Name:\n")`.
2. #1 will help here, but you may want to look at the `fmt.Scanf` function. It lets you provide a format string like this `fmt.Scanf("%d", &age1)` to explicitly look for an integer or whole number in the input.
3. You've declared the `name1` and `name2` variables as `int`. I think they should be `string`.
4. Remove the `&` before the variables in the line where you print out the average. It's not needed there.

Hopefully, that gets you closer to where you want to be.

Comment: Thank you very much, fm2279. Since I'm a newbie to Go, I still struggle with some syntaxes and declarations, and, that said, your corrections were great!

Comment: Happy to help, @apuglia. Could you accept my answer if it was useful?

Answer (score -1):

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"strconv"
)


func main() {

var name1, age1 , name2, age2 string
var average float32

fmt.Println("First person info:")
fmt.Print("Name: ")
fmt.Scan(&name1)
fmt.Print("Age: ")
fmt.Scan(&age1)
fmt.Println("Second person info:")
fmt.Print("Name: ")
fmt.Scan(&name2)
fmt.Print("Age: ")
fmt.Scan(&age2)

ageInt1, _ := strconv.Atoi(age1)
ageInt2, _ := strconv.Atoi(age2)

average = float32(( ageInt1+ ageInt2) / 2)
fmt.Printf("\nThe average age of %v and %v is %f years", name1, name2, average)


}

//output will be like
//enter code here
//First person info:
//Name: Joh
//Age: 23
//Second person info:
//Name: Doe
//Age: 34

//The average age of Joh and Doe is 28.000000 years%
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments! It worked here!